# Can I simply copy a factory image from an HDD to an SSD before going through the first-time Windows setup, and keep Windows genuine?

Tags: windows-7, disk-image, factory-defaults, windows-genuine-advantage

I got my laptop back from the repair facility today, and found it was reset with "factory preload software," which includes a fresh install of Windows 7 Professional. I started my laptop to see it boot into the first-time Windows setup wizard, and shut down the computer at this point.

Now, can I copy an image of this hard disk drive onto a new solid-state drive, and expect the laptop to boot up properly, *and* maintain its genuine licensed copy of Windows 7 Professional? Or is the factory preload software "aware" of what disk drive it was licensed for?

I realize I simply don't know how Windows validates the genuineness of its products.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, make sure you check your partition "alignment" after cloning your HDD to SSD.  This is very common mistake and really kills the performance of your SSD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  You can replace everything in the computer except for the motherboard before triggering Windows Genuine Advantage.

From [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/oem/en/licensing/sblicensing/pages/licensing_faq.aspx): *"Generally, an end user can upgrade or replace all of the hardware components on a computer—except the motherboard—and still retain the license for the original Microsoft OEM operating system software."*

Answer (score 0):

You can boot any Linux Live Image and use the `dd` command to make an exact copy in the new drive (including partition table and everything). Like this (as root of course):

```
# dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb
```

- `if` is the *input file*, or **from where** you want to copy; in this case we use the drive's `sda` block file.
- Likewise `of` is the *output file*, or **to where** you want to copy your data, in this case we use the drive's `sdb` block file.

The copy will stop when either it's done copying the information or when it has reached the end of the second drive. `dd` doesn't report any progress so it'd seem as if the console were frozen for a long time.

Be careful, if you mix up `if` and `of` you may end up zero-ing your first drive and losing all data and partitions.